# Set cache header of Image when upload to Azure Storage using Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage

I am uploading files to an Azure Storage container and need to set the caching rules. Essentially, I want browsers to cache it forever (or as long as the browser chooses).

I'm looking at x_ms_blob_cache_control from here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee691966.aspx

However, they don't say what format the value should have. I have tried

```
"max-age:31536000"
"max-age=31536000"
```

I'm uploading via Python:

```
import azure
from azure.storage.blob import BlobService

blob_service.put_block_blob_from_path(
        container_name = container_name,
        blob_name = blob_name ,
        file_path = file_path ,
        x_ms_blob_content_type = mime_type,
        x_ms_blob_cache_control = "WHAT GOES HERE?"
    )
```

The image is downloaded every time I enter its url in my browser to view it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. It DID work when I used:

```
"max-age=31536000"
```

When I was loading just the image in Chrome (image-url in address bar), then it would not cache it. However, when I used it in a webpage as img src, then it was cached.

I'll leave this in case others have a similar issue.